# Probability of picking a bolt that isn't rusted

Tags: probability

A box has 50 bolts and 150 nuts. On examining the box, it was found that half of the bolts and half the nuts are rusted. If a bolt is chosen at random, what is the probability that the bolt is not rusted?

A) 1/4
B) 1/2
C) 1/8
D) 3/16

Comment: According to me it should be 1/2, as there are 50 bolts to choose from and 25 of them are not rusted. My math teacher says otherwise. She says we cannot ignore the nuts, and says the answer is 1/8, as there are 200 total items. I am unable to convince her that I am right.

Comment: Maybe the question is "An item is chosen at random and it is a bolt. What is the probability that it is nor rusted"?

Comment: no, that isn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructor is wrong if the language of the question is "If a **bolt** is chosen at random...."  This phrasing implies that when an object is selected at random from the box, that it is a bolt.  Given that it is a bolt, the probability it is rusted is $1/2$ as you state.

The instructor is correct if instead we are told that an **object** is chosen at random from the box.  In such a case, there are $200$ objects to be chosen, of which $25$ are bolts that are not rusted.

This illustrates the importance of using precise language to describe the event of interest.  Moreover, the second part of that sentence, "...what is the probability that the bolt is not rusted," suggests that the correct interpretation is the first one, since if the sentence had been "If an object is chosen from random,..." then the second part of the sentence would need to be written along the lines of "...what is the probability it is a bolt that is not rusted?"

Comment: That is precisely what i have been trying to explain, I am saying there is a difference between choosing a bolt and choosing an object, but my teacher begs to differ.

Comment: @Invert_DOG_about_centre_O Then your teacher is an obstinate idiot who is incapable of admitting she is wrong.  I hold a graduate degree in statistics and a bachelor's in pure mathematics.  I have taught both subjects at a college level.  The worst possible conceit of a mathematician or educator is the inability to admit being wrong.  No one is perfect.  We all make mistakes.  What makes us credible is the ability to own up to those mistakes.  Failure to do so calls into question that individual's entire reputation.